# Electric dipole interaction: flat coupling semi-classically, non flat with E.M field quantized: why ? What does that mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-optics

### Basic reminders of dipole-light interaction

In the dipolar approximation, the electric-field dipole interaction is written as:

$$H=-\mathbf{d}.\mathbf{E}(t) = -q\mathbf{r}.\mathbf{E}(t)$$
$\mathbf{r}$ being the distance between the two charge that make the dipole.

### Semi-classical modelling of quantum dipole interacting with light

Now, I start to do quantum physics and I assume that the dipole is a two level system. I thus have:

$$ \mathbf{r} = \widehat{\mathbf{r}}=\langle 0|\widehat{\mathbf{r}}|1\rangle |0\rangle \langle 1|+\langle 1|\widehat{\mathbf{r}}|0\rangle |1\rangle \langle 0|$$

Indeed, as I work with a TLS, I can decompose its operator on a qubit basis, and the diagonal elements give $0$ by symmetry because the position operator is odd, and would be integrated by an even function (square modulus of $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$).

A particular case that I will focus on now is the following:

$$q \widehat{r}=\epsilon \sigma_x$$

$$H=-q\widehat{\mathbf{r}}.\mathbf{E}(t)=\epsilon \widehat{\sigma}_x E_x(t)$$

This is the semi-classical modelling of light-matter interaction for the matter being a dipole. As we see, the coupling is **flat** in frequency (I can expand $E_x(t)=\int d \omega E_x(\omega)e^{j \omega t}$ to see it).

### Full quantum modelling

To go further, we can quantize the electric field and write down the hamiltonian. Using periodic boundary conditions, focusing on $x=0$ where the dipole is, the electric field has the form (I assume a single polarization to simplify)

$$\widehat{E_x}=\sum_k \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \omega_k}{2 \epsilon_0 V}} \left( \widehat{a}(\omega_k) e^{-j\omega_t} + \widehat{a}^{\dagger}(\omega_k) e^{j\omega_t} \right)$$

Now, the Hamiltonian takes the form:

$$H=-q\widehat{\mathbf{r}}.\mathbf{E}(t)=\widehat{\sigma}_x \sum_k \epsilon \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \omega_k}{2 \epsilon_0 V}} \left( \widehat{a}(\omega_k) e^{-j\omega_t} + \widehat{a}^{\dagger}(\omega_k) e^{j\omega_t} \right)$$

### My question

And here, we see that **the coupling is no longer flat in frequency**, in the opposite of the classical case.

This disturbs me a lot. A flat coupling has some physical interpretations. Basically in the classical modelling if I send a pulse on the TLS, once the pulse is passed, the qubit no longer evolves as a consequence of flat frequency coupling $\Leftrightarrow$ instantaneous time response (no memory effect).

In the quantum regime, the description should be more accurate physically but we should still have this no memory effect.

I don't understand.

Comment: How is the quantum case not "flat" here? Do youo mean the factor $\sqrt{\omega_k}$? Note that this is just related to how you defined your Fourier transforms in the classical and in the quantum case. If you compare $a(\omega_k)$ to $E_x(\omega)$ and make the sum over $k$ in the quantum case an integral, the two approaches should be identical. In the end, all you have done is a classical Fourier expansion of the field in one case and a quantum Fourier expansion in the other case. This has nothing to do with memory effects, it's just how you do your Fourier transforms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107425/discussion-between-wolpertinger-and-starbuck).

Comment: @Wolpertinger I wrote a new question related to our discussion. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548712/validity-of-flat-coupling-approximation-in-input-output-theory-why-is-it-calle